# Understanding the new DNX

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnx

I'm looking into DNX (ASP.NET) and I'm facing a couple of issues with this.
Under a project, in the node "References" you now see ".NET Framework 4.5.1" and ".NET Platform 5.4".

Now, I'm working on an application which is being hosted on Mongo and when installing that through Nuget, the reference only gets added to .NET Framework 4.5.1

When I'm building my application, I see a lot of errors regarding MongoDB namespace not found, despite they are colored and useable in the source code (I dohave intellisense).

Anyone who can explain me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your code is built both for the "classical CLR" and for .NET core (this is the default in file->new Project when you created the project in Visual Studio).

As it looks the MongoDB nuget package is only available for the "classical CLR", so your code cannot be built for the core CLR. One option is to drop the CoreCLR support: you can do this by removing that from the "`frameworks`" part in the `project.json` file.

Now I don't know anything about the MongoDb nuget package... maybe there is a CoreCLR version... if this is the case then you need to add that dependency for CoreCLR (Maybe someone knows whether there is support for CoreCLR at all and can extend my answer..)

Comment: I've removed the .NET Core part in the project.json file, so that's already good. But should I remove the Core also from projects referencing the project that holds the MongoDB nuget package? If so, is it correct to assume then that I need to remove .NET core support from all my packages.

Comment: Yes, since the project with reference to MongoDB cannot be built for CoreCLR... so the referencing project cannot be built for coreclr either.

Comment: Ok, I still have some errors when building but it's starting to make sense right now. Thanks for the help.